# Piping output to command and terminal

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

We have command in jenkins:

```
IMAGE_ID=$(docker build -t $REGISTRY/something/$BRANCH:latest docker/ | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $3 }')
```

That gets image id, but problem is, that we don't see build output of `docker build -t $REGISTRY/something/$BRANCH:latest docker/`.

How we should pipe output that we still could get IMAGE_ID and see output?

...and we lack skills in linux big time...

Have a good day!

Comment: Do you mean by see output, to have it printed in console ?

Comment: If yes you can use `echo $IMAGE_ID` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it you want the output of the docker build.

A solution is to use `tee` and copy the stdout of docker to stderr

```
IMAGE_ID=$(docker build -t $REGISTRY/something/$BRANCH:latest docker/ | tee /dev/stderr | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $3 }')
```